# Parse string with square brackets to json

Tags: c#, json

I would like to parse this string to Json:

```
String str="[{\"property\":\"insert_date\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]"
```

I have tried with this:

```
dynamic myObject=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str)
```

but it returns some JArray.
I would like to read values simple like:

```
String dir=myObject.direction;
```

One option is to parse string and remove square object from string. Than it would work. But i would like to do it on more proper way.

Comment: doesn't that just make it myobject[0].direction?

Comment: str contains a valid json which upon deserialization will obviously give you array and that's *proper*. If you want it as single object then you must remove square brackets from source json. I don't know what is going on in your mind. You have already done what you need to, and that is also proper.

Comment: if it is always single object, try to replace `[` and `]` and check.

Comment: If I try myobject[0].direction, i get this:
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll

I have found out, It works this way:
dynamic myObject = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<object>>(str);

Replacing [ and ] would work but i didn't want to parse string as i have described.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a class and deserialize it as a `List<ThatClass>`.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("property")]
    public string Property { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("direction")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(str);
var foo = foos.First();
Console.WriteLine(foo.Direction);
```

The other way is using `dynamic`, and simply accessing the first element of the `JArray`:

```
String str = "[{\"property\":\"insert_date\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]";
dynamic objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);
Console.WriteLine(objects[0].direction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose you simply need to do this:

```
String dir = myobject[0].direction;
```

It could be the best option I think